# How to get json filter with Ng2SearchPipeline library to export excel file in Angular 8?

Tags: excel, angular, export

I'm trying to export a json object to excel with Xlsx library, the issue is when I'm making a data filter with Ng2Search library, over view it's work for me, but when I want to export the filter data to excel It export original json no more the filter json, how can I to get or handle the filter variable to pass It to the export to excel function?

in `general.service.ts`:

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

public EXPORTAR_EXCEL(json:any,nombre:any){
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet=XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'All Data Export');

    /* save to file */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, nombre+'.xlsx');
}
```

In html view:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3"> 
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="buscar" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Buscar">                    
</div>  

<div class="col-4" *ngFor="let p of productos | filter : buscar;let i = index">
```

In Ts file:

```
exportar($event)
{    
  this.generalService.EXPORTAR_EXCEL(this.productos,"Productos"+this.generalService.DATE_FORMAT(new Date()));
}
```

Thank you!

Judlup.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular v4 - Applying filters to *ngFor using pipes</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      body {font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
    </style>
    <!-- Polyfills -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for comment, but I don't understand your solution, could you example me It? Best regards.